# quarto revealjs rerender if included file changes

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I'm using `quarto` to create `revealjs` slides. I have a main file `science.qmd`
that looks similar to this

```
---
title: "title"
author: "me"
date: "2023-09-01"
toc: false
chalkboard: true
---


{{< include slides/_basics.qmd >}}
{{< include slides/_datenbasiert.qmd >}}
{{< include slides/_bias.qmd >}}
```

I.e., this file is purely thought of as the driver, and the main content is stored inside the `_*.qmd` files.

My `_quarto.yml` looks like this:

```markdown
project:
  title: "title"
  output-dir: docs
  preview:
    port: 4200
    browser: true
    watch-inputs: true

execute:
  freeze: auto  # re-render only when source changes
  # cache: true

editor:
  render-on-save: true

format:
  revealjs:
    theme: [default,styles.scss]
    highlight-style: dracula
    code-line-numbers: true
    code-fold: false
    code-tools: true
    code-copy: true
    navigation-mode: vertical
    controls-layout: bottom-right
    controls-tutorial: true
```

Now I run

```
poetry run quarto preview /Users/me/Repos/myfolder --render all
```

To render the presentation.

My problem is that I am unable to trigger a re-render in the case that the contents of the `_*.qmd` files is changed. I have enabled "Render on save" and whenever I change the content of the `science.qmd` file, it also runs the re-rendering.

Can I force the presentation to re-render whenever I change one of the included `.qmd` files?

Comment: What about a [targets](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/literate-programming.html) pipeline?

Answer (score -6):

It appears that you are using Quarto to generate reveal.js presentations from Markdown files and you want to trigger a re-render whenever one of the included `_*.qmd` files changes. Quarto should automatically handle re-rendering when the included files change, but if it's not working as expected, you can try the following steps to ensure that the rendering process updates when the included files are modified:

1. **Check Quarto Version**: Ensure that you are using a version of Quarto that supports automatic re-rendering on file changes. Quarto may have received updates that improve this feature. You can check for updates by running:

   ```
   poetry update quarto
   ```
2. **Check YAML Configuration**: Ensure that your `_quarto.yml` configuration is correctly set up to enable automatic re-rendering:

   ```yaml
   execute:
     freeze: auto  # re-render only when source changes
   editor:
     render-on-save: true
   ```

   The `freeze: auto` option should trigger re-rendering when source files change. The `render-on-save: true` option should trigger re-rendering when you save a file.
3. **Check File Inclusion**: Make sure that the `_*.qmd` files are correctly included in your `science.qmd` file using the Quarto include syntax. For example:

   ```markdown
   {{< include slides/_basics.qmd >}}
   {{< include slides/_datenbasiert.qmd >}}
   {{< include slides/_bias.qmd >}}
   ```

   Ensure that the file paths are correct and relative to the location of your `science.qmd` file.
4. **Check File Permissions**: Ensure that you have the necessary read permissions for the included files, so Quarto can monitor changes in those files.
5. **File System Watching**: Quarto relies on the file system watching mechanism to detect changes in included files. Sometimes, issues with file system watching can prevent updates. Ensure that your operating system and file system support the file watching mechanism properly.
6. **Rebuild or Clean**: In some cases, you may want to try rebuilding your project or cleaning the project's cache to force a full re-render:

   ```
   poetry run quarto clean /Users/me/Repos/myfolder
   poetry run quarto render /Users/me/Repos/myfolder
   ```

   This will clear any cached data and force a re-render of all files.
7. **Debugging**: If the issue persists, consider running Quarto in debug mode to get more information about what's happening under the hood. You can use the `--verbose` or `--debug` option when running Quarto to see detailed logs.

   ```
   poetry run quarto preview /Users/me/Repos/myfolder --render all --verbose
   ```

   Review the logs for any error messages or information related to file monitoring and rendering.

By following these steps, you should be able to ensure that Quarto re-renders your presentation whenever the included `_*.qmd` files are changed. If you continue to face issues, you may want to consult Quarto's documentation or community forums for additional support.